# How to upload Flask FIleStorage object file to another API?

Tags: python, flask, imagekit

I am creating an API in Flask where the user uploads file to the `/upload` endpoint. On receiving the file from Flask API, I want to upload the image file to imageKit API directly without first saving it on device and then reading with open() function.

Here's what I tried:

**`/upload` API endpoint:**

```py
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def picture_upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    response = webz.picture_upload(file)
    return "Awesome", 200
```

**webz.py**

```py
def picture_upload(file):
    imagekit.upload(
        file = file.read(),
        file_name = "profile.png",
    )
    return True
```

[image]

But it creates a file of 41 bytes when the uploaded file is of 2 MB.

Comment: Looking at the imagekit docs it looks like the upload function is expecting to be passed an open file for reading rather than the file contents. Try `file=file` rather than `file=file.read()`.

Comment: @EAW I tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: Use [`upload_file()`](https://github.com/imagekit-developer/imagekit-python?tab=readme-ov-file#file-upload) instead of `upload()`  on `imagekit` it accepts file binary & many more options.

Comment: If binary doesn't work convert file object into **Base64** encoded string.